# Den Hut unter etwas stellen

Tags: idiom

Als ich den *Prozess* von Kafka las, begegnete mir ein Satz, den ich nicht verstand:

> Zu diesem Zwecke würde es natürlich nicht genügen, daß K. wie die anderen im Gang saß und den Hut unter die Bank stellte.

Was bedeutet "den Hut unter die Bank stellen"? Ist das eine idiomatische Wendung? Man nutzt die derzeit oder das ist ein Archaismus?

**UPD**:

Die Frage scheint sinnlos, aber Ich habe sie gestellt, weil ich die Bedeutung des Worts 'Bank' missverstanden habe. K. arbeitet in einer Bank, deswegen habe ich gedacht, es geht um seine Stelle.

Comment: Ich glaube, das heißt einfach nur, seinen Hut unter die Bank zu stellen

Comment: @flipback Die Frage ist auch dann, wenn man weiss, dass die (Sitz)bank gemeint war, nicht sinnlos - Ich hätte den Satz auf Anhieb auch nicht verstanden und es brauchte ein bisschen Nachdenken, um auf eine (mögliche) Erklärung zu kommen.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Den Hut unter die Bank stellen" ist keine mir bekannte Redewendung, die "Liste deutscher Redewendungen" auf Wikipedia kennt den Ausdruck auch nicht.

Wenn man sich aber überlegt, warum das jemand täte, kann ich mir vorstellen, dass derjenige sich auf eine längere Warte- bzw. Anwesenheitszeit einstellt - Ansonsten würde er ja seinen Hut in der Hand behalten. Möglicherweise wollte Kafka das ausdrücken und (das ist jetzt ein bißchen hypothetischer) wurde zu Zeiten als "Mann" noch Hut trug, auch wesentlich besser verstanden.

Comment: Innerhalb von Gebäuden nimmt der Herr (zur Zeit Kafkas) stets den Hut ab. Wie tofro sagte, würde man ihn normalerweise in der Hand behalten, den Hut wegzulegen bedeutet, daß ein längerer Aufenthalt erwartet wird. Und in diesem Fall würde man den Hut auf einem Hutständer oder einem Haken aufbewahren (noch James Bond in Moneypennys Büro macht das so). Daß nicht einmal diese Möglichkeit eingeräumt wird, bedeutet, daß jemand *lange warten* muß und *geringen Status* hat.

Comment: Normalerweise *legt* man einen Hut doch ab, oder? Ich frage mich, wieso hier *stellen* verwendet wird.

Comment: Ich gehe zu Zeiten von Kafka in Prag da von einem Zylinder oder was ähnlich Monströsem aus - Das würde man wohl eher stellen.